# How to get a list of object with AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I am trying to generate a list with AJAX and post it to controller. Here is my code so far;

```
var objects = new Array();

here is a loop {
var object = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: 3
        };

objects[i] = object;
i++;
}

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/Poster",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(objects),
        success: function (result) {
            alert("posted");
        }
    });
```

Am I following the right way till here?

And in back end I created a model class;

```
public class ObjectModel
{
    public int a {get; set;}
    public int b {get; set;}
    public int c {get; set;}
}
```

Now I am trying to get this object list to my controller. After a research I tried create a controller method that takes an object list as parameter;

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Poster(List<ObJectModel> olist)
    { 
    }
```

But I can't define a list in my controller. What am I supposed to do from now? And should I make any changes in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try post without JSON.stringify just objects?

Comment: and add attribute [HttpPost] to Poster

Comment: default model binder can't process List<T>,you can create a model binder for your type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added System.Collections namepace to my controller. And I can define List now. After I added [HttpPost] attribute to my method and make public my class properties now there isn't any problem. My main problem was the System.Collections namespace. I successfully passed my object list to my controller.

Comment: In future add compile errors to question. It's dificult to find problem without all information. Also try this http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ very useful and offer solution for this and many other issues.

Comment: I'm not able to mark your answer as solution, because question is not mine, but I make upvote, because you find solution for your problem, but thenn add more useful information.

Comment: Yes you're rihgt. I will provide more information in my future questions. Thank you for your advice about resharper. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data: objects
```

instead of

```
data: JSON.stringify(objects)
```

Add attribute to `Poster`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Poster(List<ObJectModel> olist)
```

Change ObjectModel

```
public class ObjectModel
{
    public int a {get; set;}
    public int b {get; set;}
    public int c {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I have already added HttpPost attr. to my method. So I still cant define a list as a parameter. I think my main problem is this. I can define IList, Arraylist etc but can't List.

Comment: did you change property to public?

Comment: do you return something from Poster?

Comment: First of all thank you for your all effort. I have resolved my problem. Please read my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data: $.param(objects),
```

insted of

```
data: JSON.stringify(objects),
```

Comment: what the difference, why did you copy two times the same string from my answer?

Comment: sorry simple copy paste mistake see the updated answer.